# JQuery Mobile Back Button Functionality

Tags: jquery-mobile

I think this must be a common scenario-- but I can't seem to find a solution.

JQueryMobile site with authentication functionality:

1. Link on all pages takes user to dynamically loaded authentication page
2. All pages have back button functionality
3. A bad username and password causes an ajax form submission
4. Clicking the back button in this scenario takes you back to the authentication page (which makes sense because that's where you came from-- but if I input a bad password five times, I have to click on the back button five times before I get back to where I came from)

I guess what I want is to have the ajax form submission for logging in taken out of the "hash" history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this would be by keeping track of the failed attempts `numberOfAttempts++`. Then using `history.go(-numberOfAttempts);` when the back button is clicked.